# Find a limit containing an definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Let $f\in C[0,1]$ and $f\ge 0$. Find the limit:  $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)^{1/n}$$

**My thought:**
We denote $f_n(x) = f(x)^n$. If we could show that $f_n(x)\to f$ uniformly then we could interchange the limit with the integral, but we don't know much about $f$ in order to figure this out.

I guess the $f\ge 0$ should come in handy, but I don't know how.

I'd be glad for a guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: it is clear equal $\max_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle M = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} f(x)$. If $M = 0$, the limits is clearly $0$, so suppose $M > 0$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, there is such $x_0 \in [0, 1]$ that $f(x_0) = M$.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$.  There exists such $\delta > 0$ that $M - \varepsilon < f(x) \leqslant M$ for $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$. Therefore

$$2 \delta \cdot \big[ M - \varepsilon \big]^n \leqslant \int \limits_{x_0 - \delta}^{x_0 + \delta} \big( f(x) \big)^n \, \mathrm{d} x \leqslant \int \limits_0^1 \big( f(x) \big)^n \, \mathrm{d} x \leqslant M^n$$

so

$$\sqrt[n]{2 \delta} \cdot [M - \varepsilon] \leqslant \left( \int \limits_0^1 \big( f(x) \big)^n \, \mathrm{d} x \right)^{1/n} \leqslant M.$$

Since LHS can be made bigger than $M - 2\varepsilon$ by taking sufficiently large $n$ and since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, the limits is $M$.

---

Note the similarity of the above example to the limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n + 5^n + 11^n}{3}} = 11.$$

The proof is basically the same.

Comment: Thanks. What was your intuition behind this solution please?

Comment: @Elimination Suppose $a < b$. Then $\int \limits_0^1 a^n \, \mathrm{d} x = a^n$ and $\int \limits_{0}^{\varepsilon} b^n \, \mathrm{d} x = \varepsilon \cdot b^n$. Since $a < b$, for large $n$ the second integral will eventually get bigger. From this simple example it is evident that length of interval is less material than the magnitude of integrated function. That's why the expression $$\left( \int \limits_0^1 \big( f(x) \big)^n \, \mathrm{d} x \right)^{1/n}$$ gets as big as $f(x)$ can be, even if it does so on a tiny subinterval.

Answer (score 1):

We will begin by writing the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)^{1/n}$$ as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{1/n\left(ln( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx) \right)}$$
So, we will examine how $\lim_{n\to\infty}{1/n\left(ln( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx) \right)}$ behaves.

Since $f\in C[0,1]$, we can use L'Hôpital's rule on $\lim_{n\to\infty}{1/n\left(ln( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx) \right)}$ on the n (like $df/dn$) and then we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({\left( \int_0^1 n(f(x))^{n-1}dx \right)/\left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)}\right)$$
Now if we show that $$\left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)\ge\left( \int_0^1 n(f(x))^{n-1}dx \right)$$ then we will have that the first integral (on the left) goes to infinity faster than the second one, therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({\left( \int_0^1 n(f(x))^{n-1}dx \right)/\left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)}\right)=0 $$ and so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{1/n\left(ln( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx) \right)}=e^{0}=1$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)^{1/n}=1$$
If$$\left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)\ge\left( \int_0^1 n(f(x))^{n-1}dx \right)$$ then $$(f(x))^n\ge n(f(x))^{n-1}$$ $$f(x)(f(x))^{n-1}\ge n(f(x))^{n-1}$$ and because if $f\ge 0$, $f(x)\ge n$. 
So, if $f(x)\ge n$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{1/n\left(ln( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx) \right)}=e^{0}=1$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)^{1/n}=1$$ otherwise $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({\left( \int_0^1 n(f(x))^{n-1}dx \right)/\left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)}\right)=\infty$$ and so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{1/n\left(ln( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx) \right)}=e^{\infty}=\infty$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)^{1/n}=\infty$$
If $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in D_f$, I believe it is clear from the start that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_0^1 (f(x))^n \ dx \right)^{1/n}=0$$